# How do you prevent your connections from seeing your work anniversaries on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

Every year I get a flood of "Congratulations on your work anniversary" posts or e-mails from random recruiters / students / co-workers/ whoever. I want to prevent that from happening.

I've already disabled ME receiving notification of OTHERS' work anniversary. I am specifically asking how I can disable/prevent OTHERS' from receiving a notification or "Say Congrats!" button for MY anniversaries.